# How much of the iOS filesystem is accessible without root access or a jailbreak?

Tags: ios, filesystems, jailbreak

I was wondering how far a sandboxed user can actually dig into the filesystem on the iOS operating system, with a sandbox escape exploit, of course. I am aware you are capable of accessing the Documents folder of the specific sandboxed app and possibly other folders or files within the app. My question here is really what capabilities would a sandbox exploit have exactly? How much of the filesystem can be viewed, edited, and/or written to with said exploit?

Comment: That's it. Your app can only access your own app's sandbox.

Comment: I understand that, but what other parts of the iOS filesystem can be accessed without root access?

Comment: I just told you and you just said you understood. A 3rd party app can only access its own sandbox. That's it. I'm not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks rmaddy!